# Regex split while reading from file

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have a text file and I am reading it line by line.

I want to split a single line with ','.

But I want the commas which are inside quotes "" to be skipped.

I have tried following regex and it is not working correctly.

How to do it.

The contents of file are

```
"Mobile","Custom1","Custom2","Custom3","First Name"
"61402818083","service","in Portsmith","is","First Name"
"61402818083","service","in Parramatta Park","is","First Name"
"61402818083","services","in postcodes 3000, 4000","are","First Name"
"61402818083","services","in postcodes 3000, 4000, 5000","are","First Name"
"61402818083","services",,"are","First Name"
```

The regex is as follows

```
,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

This regex is outputting the following for line 5

```
"61402818083"
,"First Name"
"services"
,"First Name"
"in postcodes 3000, 4000, 5000"
,"First Name"
"are"
"First Name"
"First Name"
```

The result should be as follows

```
"61402818083"
"services"
"in postcodes 3000, 4000, 5000"
"are"
"First Name"
```

Comment: "it is not working correctly" is about as useful for getting help as going to the doctor and saying "I have pain."

Comment: @maraca added the desired result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string line = "\"61402818083\",\"services\",\"in postcodes 3000, 4000\",\"are\",\"First Name\"";
        var reg = new Regex("\".*?\"");
        var matches = reg.Matches(line);
        foreach (var item in matches)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
"61402818083"
"services"
"in postcodes 3000, 4000"
"are"
"First Name"
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5GxxIo

One more possible solution:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string line = "\"61402818083\",\"services\",\"in postcodes 3000, 4000\",\"are\",\"First Name\"";
        Console.WriteLine(line.ToString());
        var reg = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var matches = reg.Matches(line);
        foreach (Match match in reg.Matches(line))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Value.TrimStart(','));
        }
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rRml2D

Comment: Like this you could also handle escaped `"` by using `"\".*?[^\\\\]\""` I don't know how the policy on this is.

Comment: used your first fix.

Second fix also matches the full string as a whole.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Seems that you're trying to parse a comma separated file (even if the file extension is different to csv). Try with this.

```
using (TextFieldParser reader = new TextFieldParser(@"c:\yourpath\file.csv"))
{
    reader.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    reader.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!reader.EndOfData) 
    {
        //Processing a line of the file
        string[] fields = reader.ReadFields();
        // now fields contains 5 elements, e.g.
        // fields[0] = "61402818083"
        // fields[1] = "services"
        // fields[2] = "in postcodes 3000, 4000, 5000"
        // fields[3] = "are"
        // fields[4] = "First Name"
    }
}
```

**Note**

It's required to add `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as reference in your project

Comment: its not a csv file but a txt file and i am only reading one line at a time

Comment: you can try anyway, the format of your file is the same of a csv.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this just by joining strings one by one.

Example (not tested)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

int counter = 0;
string line = String.Empty;

StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder();

StreamReader file = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");

while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    newString.Append(line + ",");
}

file.Close();

newString.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
,(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)

     ^^
```

Your regex is correct.It has an unnecessary `capturing group` which turned out to be the evil.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/10